# mysql dump throwing "-bash: 32: command not found" and creating a 20 bytes files

Tags: mysql

```
mysqldump -u(username) -p(password) --no-data --quick
--skip-add-drop-table --replace (database_name) authors_main
```

getting commond not found error while trying to run above command on UNIX. (this used to work completely fine a month back)

Thanks for all the help in anticipation

Comment: Do you have any spaces in your password? Are you quoting it properly?

Comment: Sounds like `mysqldump` isn't on your `PATH`. Where is the `mysqldump` binary?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check whether your password has special characters like `!` or `#` or `@` etc and  make sure they are not wrongly interpreted by shell